# SQOOP Import all tables in a specific Schema from ORACLE Database

Tags: oracle, hadoop, import, sqoop

I am trying to import all tables in a specific schema from Oracle database with Sqoop command :

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:server:port:database --username x --password y --warehouse-dir warehouse-dir --hive-import --create-hive-table
```

But this Oracle database has more schemas and I need only to import all tables from one specific schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the additional parameter `--exclude-tables <tables>`, which refers to a comma separated list of tables to exclude from import process.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html

If you use `--import-all-tables` the tables to be imported will be those that the user who connects by jdbc has select privilege over. Basically, those tables that the user see in `all_tables`.

To limit the list, another option is to use a different user, one with limited select over the tables you want to export to.